# Selecting Child fields of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple div with child fields. These child fields share similar names. I am trying to show child fields of a particular. But I am only getting child fields of first div. 
Does it have anything to do it with child Field's `name`

**HTML**

```
 <div class="row childFields" id="parent-question1">
        <p class="subtitle">Give full details here: </p>
        <div class="col-md-6 colChildFields" style="display:none" name="condition">
            <label class="pocLabel">Nature of Condition</label>
            <input type="text" name="condition" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 colChildFields" style="display:none" name="datesAndDuration">
            <label class="pocLabel">Dates and Duration</label>
            <input type="text" name="datesAndDuration" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 colChildFields" style="display:none" name="doctorName">
            <label class="pocLabel">Name Of Doctor</label>
            <input type="text" name="doctorName" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 colChildFields" style="display:none" name="hospitalName">
            <label class="pocLabel">Name of Hospital</label>
            <input type="text" name="hospitalName" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 colChildFields" style="display:none" name="hospitalAddress">
            <label class="pocLabel">Address of Hospital</label>
            <input type="text" name="hospitalAddress" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row childFields" id="parent-question2">
        <p class="subtitle">Give full details here: </p>
        <div class="col-md-6 colChildFields" style="display:none" name="condition">
            <label class="pocLabel">Nature of Condition</label>
            <input type="text" name="condition" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 colChildFields" style="display:none" name="datesAndDuration">
            <label class="pocLabel">Dates and Duration</label>
            <input type="text" name="datesAndDuration" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 colChildFields" style="display:none" name="doctorName">
            <label class="pocLabel">Name Of Doctor</label>
            <input type="text" name="doctorName" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 colChildFields" style="display:none" name="hospitalName">
            <label class="pocLabel">Name of Hospital</label>
            <input type="text" name="hospitalName" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 colChildFields" style="display:none" name="hospitalAddress">
            <label class="pocLabel">Address of Hospital</label>
            <input type="text" name="hospitalAddress" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row childFields" id="parent-question3">
        <p class="subtitle">Give full details here: </p>
        <div class="col-md-6 colChildFields" style="display:none" name="condition">
            <label class="pocLabel">Nature of Condition</label>
            <input type="text" name="condition" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 colChildFields" style="display:none" name="datesAndDuration">
            <label class="pocLabel">Dates and Duration</label>
            <input type="text" name="datesAndDuration" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 colChildFields" style="display:none" name="doctorName">
            <label class="pocLabel">Name Of Doctor</label>
            <input type="text" name="doctorName" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 colChildFields" style="display:none" name="hospitalName">
            <label class="pocLabel">Name of Hospital</label>
            <input type="text" name="hospitalName" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 colChildFields" style="display:none" name="hospitalAddress">
            <label class="pocLabel">Address of Hospital</label>
            <input type="text" name="hospitalAddress" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var childFieldDivId = '#parent-'+fieldName;
$(childFieldDivId).find('div').each(function(i, childField){
  $(childField).show();
});
```

Comment: how do you get `fieldName` and `childField`? can you post that code also?

Comment: why don't you just do `$(childFieldDivId).find('div > *').show()`?

Comment: PS, this is an excellent question to create a jsFiddle for

Comment: Oh Yes! Sorry forgot to select an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var childFieldDivId = '#parent-'+fieldName;
$(childFieldDivId).find('div').each(function(index, value){
  $(this).show();
});
```

<kbd>*[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pYALS/1/)*</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var childFieldDivId = '#parent-'+fieldName;
$('.subtitle').on('click', function(){ // not sure you need onclick handler
    $(this).siblings().show();
});
```

### Demo **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/HMzRM/)**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping and calling `show()`, call `show()` on the entire selector - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8XKmP/1/)

```
var childFieldDivId = '#parent-'+fieldName;
$(childFieldDivId).find('div').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to show all children of that div

```
var childFieldDivId = '#parent-'+fieldName;
$(childFieldDivId).children('div').show();
```